Parameterization by arc length: the concept
Can someone let me know if my understanding of parameterization by arc length is correct?
If we have a regular parameterized differentiable curve $\alpha: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, it is parameterized by the parameter $t$ which we can think about as time. But we can also choose for $t$ to already represent the arc length (with the relevant integral formula) measured from some point, which makes $| \alpha '(t) | = 1$. This type of parameterization is what is called parameterization by arc length.
Is this correct?

Yes, that’s correct. A car can drive along a road at different speeds at different times. The driver however can choose to maintain a constant speed of 1 kilometer per minute.

If you would like to extend the physical description, you can think of parametrization by arc length as describing a trajectory that traverses your curve at constant unit speed.  The velocity isn't constant (unless moving in a straight line), but it's magnitude is. So for every unit of time on the clock, the moving point has covered one unit of distance.
